# EventHandler in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create an event handler which displays some text whenever a button is clicked .

I can do it using

```
<asp:button id="btn1" runat="server" onClick="btn1_clicked" />
<asp:label id="lbl1" runat="server"  />
```

in the aspx.cs file

```
public void btn1_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lbl1.Text = "Text goes here";
}
```

However when I try to create the event handler using

```
public void btn1_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   btn1.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick);
}
public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lbl1.Text = "Text goes here";
}
```

It gives me an error.

What is the correct way to create the event handler?

Comment: You want to create an event-handler when this event was already handled? You must admit yourself that there must something wrong.

Comment: Why would you create a click even handler in the original button click event handler???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the event handler at

```
Page_Load

btn1.Click += (o,e)=>{  lbl1.Text = "";  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to create a new event handler because `btn1_clicked` is your click event handler. Just put your code in it.

```
public void btn1_clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  lbl1.Text = "Text goes here";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Event Handler should be initialized in Page Load or Page_Init event
btn1.Click += new EventHandler(OnClick);